# Add and edit permissions disappear when debug turned off in Django

Tags: python, django

I am deploying a website that has an `/admin/` page where staff and the superuser access the database tables.

In `settings.py` I changed these settings to put the site into production mode.

> DEBUG = False
>
> TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

Issue is this has caused my admin site to show only black links on the applications where i cannot view, edit or add rows to the tables even if logged in as a super user.

What settings have i got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here in this self answer:

[django on apache - admin page links are VISIBLE but not CLICKABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498466/django-on-apache-admin-page-links-are-visible-but-not-clickable)

Issue is i should be using a separate admin.py file, not putting things that should be in there in the model.py file.